Connecting Next.js with Mongo DB
I am a beginner JavaScript Developer studying next.js and working with the connection of Next.js and MongoDB, and I got this error.
It shows that internal server message with status code: 500.

No response is returned from route handler '${this.resolvedPagePath}'. Ensure you return a `Response` or a `NextResponse` in all branches of your handler

Can someone guide me how to solve it?
Route.js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import connectionToDatabase from "../../../../lib/mongose";
import User from "../../../../models/User";

export async function POST(request) {
    try {
        await connectionToDatabase()
        const {name, email} = await request.json();
        const newUser = new User({name, email});
        await newUser.save();
        return NextResponse.json(newUser, {status: 201})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

User.js:
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : {type: String},
    email: {type: String, required: true}
})

const User = mongoose.model.User || mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
export default User;


Mongose.js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connectionToDatabase = async () =>{
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MongoURL)
        console.log("Connected to DB")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)   
    }
}

export default connectionToDatabase;


I'm assuming this is in reference to your POST function? Should that go into the catch block, it isn't returning anything.
